# Printing with Xam.Plugin.Bluetooth

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I've tried to print from an Android tablet from C# code (Xamarin). Using the statement `device.Write(STRING_TEXT)` where device is the handle of the bluetooth and the STRING_TEXT is the message (string not byte[]!!!) the printer does not recognize the new line so the text printed at every '\n' jumps to another line, but not at the starting position.

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to print a string with newline inside this way `("Tutto bene\n stampa di prova")`

The result is "Tutto bene" in the first line and in the second line below "stampa di prova" in the position at the right of the first.

I expect:
Tutto bene (at the first position)
stampa di prova (at the first position below)

Comment: Try using “\r\n”

Comment: Good @Jason ! I used before Environement.NewLine that is composed by '\r' and \'n' but did not run..